# smtp-validate-email Uncaught exception 'SMTP_Validate_Email_Exception_Timeout'

Tags: php, email-verification

https://github.com/zytzagoo/smtp-validate-email/blob/master/smtp-validate-email.php
   to check the existence of mail addresses with some modification

---

```
<?php

require('smtp-validate-email.php');

$from = 'removed'; // for SMTP FROM:<> command
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('mailverf', $con);

$sql="SELECT * 
FROM  `mailvalid` where statut=0 limit 0,30";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

        $email = $row['mail'];

        $validator = new SMTP_Validate_Email($email, $from);
        $smtp_results = $validator->validate();
        $mail=str_replace(' ','',$row['mail']);
        // var_dump($smtp_results);
        if($smtp_results[$email])
        {
            $sql1="UPDATE  mailvalid SET  statut = 1 WHERE  id =".$row['id']."";
            mysql_query($sql1) or  die(mysql_error());
        }
        else
        {

            $sql2="INSERT INTO mailnonvalid (mail) VALUES ('".$row['mail']."')";
            mysql_query($sql2) or  die(mysql_error());

            $sql3="DELETE FROM mailvalid WHERE id = ".$row['id']."";
            mysql_query($sql3) or  die(mysql_error());
        }
        // var_dump($email);
        echo $row['id'].'</br>';
    } 

    $sql="SELECT * 
    FROM  `mailvalid` where statut=0 limit 0,30";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error()); 
    }

    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<script>window.location.reload(); </script>';}else {echo 'end';}
    }
}

?>
```

---

it's good it works, except that after some time this error message appears:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SMTP_Validate_Email_Exception_Timeout' with message 'Timed out in recv' in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ verif \ smtp-validate-email.php: 626
Stack trace:
# 0 C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ verif \ smtp -validate-email.php (650) SMTP_Validate_Email-> recv (3)
# 1 C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ verif \ smtp-validate-email.php (554) SMTP_Validate_Email-> expect (Array, 3)
# 2 C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ verif \ smtp-validate-email.php (311) SMTP_Validate_Email-> rset ()
# 3 C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ verif \ index.php (28): SMTP_Validate_Email-> validate ()
# 4 {main} thrown in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ verif \ smtp-validate-email.php on line 626
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the code you've linked to takes the email address, looks up the MX records related to the domain and then connects to the SMTP server related to that domain and asks it if the email address is valid.

You're seeing the current error because the server being asked doesn't respond.

There could be a few reasons for that, the server might not be up, the email address might be nonsense and the domain might not exist at all.

If it was me I'd wrap the validate in a try catch and if i caught the 'SMTP_Validate_Email_Exception_Timeout' error then I'd flag the address as potentially not real. Then sometime later I'd go back and check to see if i could validate the address again.

EDIT

Just to answer your question below.

You could try replacing the code you have in your while loop with this:

```
$email = $row['mail'];

$validator = new SMTP_Validate_Email($email, $from);
$emailError = false;

    try 
    {
        $smtp_results = $validator->validate();
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        $emailError = true;
    }

    $mail=str_replace(' ','',$row['mail']);
    // var_dump($smtp_results);
    if($smtp_results[$email] && !$emailError)
    {
        $sql1="UPDATE  mailvalid SET  statut = 1 WHERE  id =".$row['id']."";
        mysql_query($sql1) or  die(mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
        $emailError = false;
        $sql2="INSERT INTO mailnonvalid (mail) VALUES ('".$row['mail']."')";
        mysql_query($sql2) or  die(mysql_error());

        $sql3="DELETE FROM mailvalid WHERE id = ".$row['id']."";
        mysql_query($sql3) or  die(mysql_error());
    }
    // var_dump($email);
    echo $row['id'].'</br>';
```

Now if it hits an error it will treat the email address as if it's not in $smtp_results.

Try that and see how it goes.

Comment: is it possible that when detected this error, delete this email address and continuous analysis

Comment: Check the above and see if it's ok

Answer (score 0):

You're best to ignore it because:

1. The smtp-validate-email class can take in multiple email addresses and any one of them can kick up the error.
2. If multiple smtp servers exist for a domain (gmail addresses, for example, may consult multiple SMTP servers - I'm getting around 8?) only one needs to confirm the address for that address not to be bounced (which is all the class REALLY checks for).

It would have to be fixed in the class itself...